# Python tweepy tendencias y tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

Tengo el siguiente código para conseguir las tendencias y que me muestre los tweets que se han hecho desde madrid

```
trends1 = api.trends_place(1)
trends = set([trend['name'] for trend in trends1[0]['trends']])
print trends
```

pero al ejecutarlo me saca todo este párrafo,dentro se encuentran las tendencias pero por algún motivo me saca todo ese código basura

```
set([u'#\uc774\uc0ac\ub78c_\uc5f0\uc131\ubd84\uc704\uae30_\ubd04\uc5ec\ub984\uac00\uc744\uaca8\uc6b8', u'#\u0645\u062c\u0644\u0633_\u0627\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0647_2016', u'Diego Costa', u'#PBBLuckyBunnyElisse', u'#\u771f\u7530\u4e38', u'#azfey', u'Ander Herrera', u'#\u0627\u0645_\u0628\u064a_\u0633\u064a_\u0628\u0631\u0648_\u062a\u062d\u0627\u0631\u0628_\u0627\u0644\u0646\u0635\u0631', u'#Gentiloni', u'#KMJSWhiteChristmas', u'#inmezzora', u'#\u0647\u062f\u064a\u062a\u064a_\u0631\u0648\u0627\u062a\u0631_\u0647\u0648\u0627\u0648\u064a_\u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f', u'\u73fe\u4f4f\u6240', u'#EXO100thCONCERT', u'#SundayMorning', u'#\u4e43\u6728\u5742\u5de5\u4e8b\u4e2d', u'#\u0635\u0648\u062a_\u062a\u062d\u0628\u0647_\u062d\u064a\u0644', u'#BoybandPHWinners', u'Mandzukic', u'#PolisiminYan\u0131nday\u0131m', u'\u7fbd\u751f\u304f\u3093', u'#OLSRFC', u'#Kans\u0131zVatans\u0131zlar', u'#MeDesperteTempranoY', u'#HappySeungriDay', u'#CagliariNapoli', u'#VoiceIndiaS2', u'#\u3069\u3046\u3067\u3082\u3044\u3044\u500b\u4eba\u60c5\u5831\u3092\u6652\u305d\u3046', u'#\u0648\u064a\u0646_\u0637\u0627\u0631\u062a_\u0641\u0644\u0648\u0633\u0643', u'#Halk\u0131nG\xfcc\xfcTer\xf6r\xfcdeYenecek', u'#TorinoJuve', u'#\u304f\u3068\u6253\u3063\u3066\u30af\u30ea\u30b9\u30de\u30b9\u306a\u3089\u30ea\u30a2\u5145', u'#\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0627\u062a\u062f\u0631\u0627\u064a\u064a\u0647', u'#anisama', u'#\ub098\ub97c_\uc624\ud504\uc5d0\uc11c_\ubcf8_\ud6c4\uae30', u'#FelizDomingo', u'\u30a8\u30ad\u30b7\u30d3\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3', u'#MevlidKandili', u'#BadAdviceForTheHeartbroken', u'\uc5ec\uc911\uc0dd', u'#WeLoveTommos', u'#BMGM05', u'#GGVTropaGoals', u'#MUNTOT', u'#\u0632\u062f_\u0631\u0635\u064a\u062f\u064357', u'Tati Quebra Barraco', u'#\u0645\u0633\u0644\u0645_\u0645\u0633\u064a\u062d\u064a_\u0627\u064a\u062f_\u0648\u062d\u062f\u0647', u'Belotti', u'#enacional', u'#DomingoDetremuraSDV'])
```

como puedo conseguir que me muestre algo asi?

1-tendencia ---- 1000 tweets

2-tendencia -----23423 tweet

Comment: eso es un conjunto, con las tendencias que estás pidiendo. y no es basura, son caracteres unicode, porque hay tendencias en japonés, coreano y chino y otros que no conozco... y no hay cantidades, así que con lo que estás haciendo no puedes obtener la salida que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, lo que te está entregando actualmente está correcto y no es basura, es texto codificado en `unicode`, por lo que caracteres que no se representan en `ASCII` se suelen escribir como `\uxx` (Como caracteres Chinos, letras con tílde, etc).

Basado en la API de Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place). 
El método que estás utilizando para sacar los **trends** por área solo provee con la siguiente información:

```
[
  {
    "as_of": "2012-08-24T23:25:43Z",
    "created_at": "2012-08-24T23:24:14Z",
    "locations": [
      {
        "name": "Worldwide",
        "woeid": 1
      }
    ],
    "trends": [
      {
        "events": null,
        "name": "#GanaPuntosSi",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi"
      },
    ...
  ]
 }
[
```

Con esta llamada básicamente solo puedes saber el nombre del Trending Topic y su URL.

Por lo tanto con esta llamada no puedes saber la cantidad de Tweets que componen un Trend. Es más, es complicado responder a esa consulta dado que habría que establecer la fecha de comienzo y de término de un **hashtag** para poder contar la cantidad de Tweets emitidos en ese periodo con esa palabra clave.

Nota que un hashtag no puede aparecer y desaparecer, dado que Tweets conteniendo dicha palabra clave pueden existir desde que apareció Twitter. Aun antes que la palabra se convirtiera en Trending Topic. Por lo tanto plantearse la pregunta de cuantos Tweets tiene un Trend es más complejo de lo que parece.

Lamentablemente Twitter no provee forma de acceder a Tweets historicos (Emitidos hace tiempo) por lo tanto este tipo de consulta sería difícil de responder con la API oficial.

Si es tan importante lograr contar la cantidad de Tweets emitidos con una **keyword**, te recomiendo buscar por otras librerías que no utilicen la API oficial de Twitter, si no que exploten el sistema de búsqueda para poder hacer consultas sobre **periodos específicos de tiempo** conteniendo **palabras claves** especificas, como los Trending topic que quieres analizar.